# Are these two code different

Tags: multithreading, perl, variables, stack

```
foreach $thr (1..5)  
  {                               
     $threads[$thr]=threads->create("worker");        
  }
```

and

```
foreach (1..5)  
  {                               
     push @threads,threads->create("worker");        
  }
```

the latter works well, well the former gives warning.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                     
use strict;                                         
use threads;                                        
use threads::shared;                                
use Thread::Queue;                                  

my $queue = Thread::Queue->new();                   
my @threads;   
my $thr;
#----------------------------------------create                                
#send work first,and then creat threads, the first thread work earlier.
$queue->enqueue(1..10000);  
foreach (1..5)  
  {                               
     push @threads,threads->create("worker");        
  }                                                   

$queue->end();                      

sub worker 
  {                                        
    while (my @DataElement = $queue->dequeue(100)) 
      {
        my $tid = threads->tid();       
        #open (my $out,">>$tid.txt") or die $!; 
        print  "Threads ID:$tid\t@DataElement\n";           
        #print $out "Threads ID:$tid\t@DataElement\n";
        #close $out;    
      }                                               
  }         

#----------------------------------------cut     
my $thr_num=1;                                     
my $i;
while ($thr_num) 
  {  
    $i++;                                        
    foreach (@threads) #store threads, TRUE even if joined.
      {                            
        $thr_num = threads->list();                  
        print "threads total: $thr_num\n";              
        if ($_->is_running())
          {                     
            sleep 1; #wait                               
            next;                                   
          }                                                                                              
        if ($_->is_joinable()) 
          {                    
            $_->join();                             
          }                                                                                                
        sleep 1;# wait                       
      } 
    print $i,"\n";                                               
  }
```

this is the whole code.  and the warning is **can't call method "is_running" on an undefined value at threadqueue2(1).plx.line42. Perl exited with active threads.**

Comment: Could you please share what warning you are getting??

Comment: I have post the codes and the warning.

Comment: Perl arrays start at `0`, so maybe you want to do `0..4` instead of `1..5` and see if your warning goes away.

Comment: Yes, @xxfelixxx is right, In first code block `@threads` index 0 element is undefined but in second code block you are just pushing into the array so index 0 element is not undefined there. At line 42 ***`$_->is_running()`*** `$_` is **undefined**, that is why you are getting these warnings.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest that you shouldn't bother with an array of threads in this case, and just stick with `threads -> list`, or `threads->list(threads::joinable);`

Comment: You mean this part `while($thr_num){}`?@Sobrique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You will end up with different data structures. As you can see from this simplified version of your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

my @threads;

foreach my $thr (1 .. 5) {
  $threads[$thr] = 'A Thread';
}

say Dumper \@threads;

@threads = ();

foreach (1 .. 5) {
  push @threads, 'A Thread';
}

say Dumper \@threads;
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          'A Thread',
          'A Thread',
          'A Thread',
          'A Thread',
          'A Thread'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          'A Thread',
          'A Thread',
          'A Thread',
          'A Thread',
          'A Thread'
        ];
```

In your first example, you begin populating the array at element 1, so the first element (which has an index of 0) contains `undef`.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem.